# Alternating Current using Complex Numbers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, complex-numbers

I'm learning solving alternating current circuit using complex numbers however there is some problem that I've encountered and can't find a resource to refer to.
Basically how do I write current in time dependent form using complex numbers

Consider a very basic circuit having all 3 R, L , and C in parallel, and I have to write the current through voltage in time dependent form.  This question is very obvious but it gives me a headache using complex numbers. If i write total current using complex no.s it will be

V(1/R+ 1/wc i - wL i)
Now according to basic complex knowledge, the real part corresponds to cos(wt ) and imaginary to sin (wt). However the actual answer will have V/R with a sin (wt) and not cos(wt)

Where am I going wrong and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Look for Steinmetz transform.

Comment: Hint: You can change $A_1\sin\omega t + A_2 \cos\omega t$ to $A\sin\left(\omega t+\phi\right)$.